# Using :g to yank in quotes across multiple lines

Tags: cut-copy-paste, global-command

I was reading through the vim wiki about the power of g https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g and would like to do something similar to `:g/pattern/y A` but a little bit different.

I have an html file with tags that have a bunch of properties like this:

```
<the-tag
  prop="prop1"
</the-tag>
<the-tag
  prop="prop2"
</the-tag>
```

I would like to append to register a, the value inside the prop quotes.  Is this possible using :g or some other method?  Here is what I tried:

```
:g/prop/normal yi" A
```

but this just yanks the very last prop value instead of a whole list.  Of course I could do:

```
:g/prop/y A
```

but this would give me:

```
prop="prop1"
prop="prop2"
```

which is not what I'm looking for.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the passing of the register to `:yank` (Ex command) vs. `y` (normal mode). For the latter, instead of appending the register, it must come *before* the `y` command, and with the `"` prefix: `"Ayi"` (*with register `A`, `y`ank the `i`nner `"` double quoted text*)

```
:let @a = '' | g/prop/normal! "Ayi"
```

Note that as the yank is *characterwise*, all matches will be appended without any separator (resulting in `prop1prop2`). You could add a separator like this:

```
:let @a = '' | :g/prop/let @a .= " " | normal! "Ayi"
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was really helpful.  I'm a little confused about your second example though.  I did notice the characterwise issue with the first command and the second one did fix it, but I'm not sure I understand whats going on with the \d/ part of it.  I can see you are appending to a with let @a .= " " but how does the \d factor in?

Comment: Oh, I just added the `\d` to make it match just once in a line. Doesn't matter with `:global`, though; just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody had a similar problem: [vim yank all matches of regex group into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713617/vim-yank-all-matches-of-regex-group-into-register).

In your case `regex` will be `prop="\zs.*\ze"`.

`\zs` denotes where the match will start in the "substitution" (yanking to register), and `\ze` where to end.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different variation using `:h gn` motion:

```
let @a='' | g/prop="\zs.*\ze"/normal! "Aygn
```